# SSRS create table/list based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder

I'm not a programmer, but basically a BI person. I have created a view with all the information I want to see. I have a few columns I want to filter on before creating a report. What I want to create is a report in Report Builder in which I select a few parameters and then a report is generated with all the information in the view and filtered using the parameters.

Now, this is supposed to be very simple. But I can only get a parameter to work with a matrix, but I want to use a list or a table. I can't use a matrix since I only want to display the the data in the view/dataset, and not aggregate/sum/avg the data.

(In my quest for the answer, I found this video: https://youtu.be/MSYN0TAuB5c?t=3m46s what happens here is what I want, I just can't figure out how to get it done and they don't explain in the video.)

Can anybody help me with this? Again, I'm not big on Visual Basic etc., just SQL. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Parameter behavior is not influenced by the report layout. What do you mean you cant get a parameter to work? Are you trying to filter a dataset?

Comment: post relevant codes too

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video skips the part of where the parameter is created.

Your query should be something like "Select * from v_myview where column1 = @Value". 
Then report builder creates the parameter @Value. From there you can continue using the instruction video.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to filter the entire dataset. Thanks a lot!
[Dataset properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HdEf.png)